# get properties with reflection from an object in shared/pcl project

Tags: c#, reflection

I have an object with 500 parameters and I can not change it, because it is a shared project.
My goal is to get the property value through reflection, but I can not do it.

here is my code:

```
public class MyObjects
    {    
    public int RGP_Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime RGP_DateTime { get; set; }
    public int RGP_MCC_Numero_Serie_MS { get; set; }
    public int RGP_IDREG_1 { get; set; }
    public int RGP_IDREG_2 { get; set; }
    public int RGP_IDREG_3 { get; set; }
    public int RGP_IDREG_4 { get; set; }
    public int RGP_IDREG_5 { get; set; }
    public int RGP_IDREG_6 { get; set; }
    public int RGP_IDREG_7 { get; set; }
    public int RGP_IDREG_8 { get; set; }
    public int RGP_IDREG_9 { get; set; }
    public int RGP_IDREG_10 { get; set; }
    .......
    public int RGP_IDREG_500 { get; set; }

}
```

...

```
var profile = MyObjects;
var idProperty = GetProperty(profile.GetType().GetTypeInfo(), "RGP_IDREG_10");
```

...

**idProperty** contains the object, and up there I did.

Now, how can I obtain the value using idProperty?
basically I would get:

```
var x = MyObjects.idProperty;
```

How can i get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restore value by using this code:

```
var x = idProperty.GetValue(profile, null))
```

You can get more information here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/b05d59ty(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `idProperty` is a `PropertyInfo` object you could do something like:

```
var result = (int) idProperty.GetValue(profile,null);
```

You have to make sure to cast the value because it is returned as an `object`.